# namespace not loading correctly

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I am reading in an xml namespace through a local file.  When I am outputting I am getting

```
 &quot;&#xD;&#xA;
```

in the namespace.  What am I doing wrong?

sample namespace looks like

- xmlns="urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02"
  xmlns:dacc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03"

I am loading the namespace as follows:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("loadNamespaces.txt");

XmlNode ShipmentReceiptNotification0Node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ShipmentReceiptNotification", contents);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That's very crazy.

Comment: I have a namespace that has 100 xmlns:name ends in ...\.xsd>

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need these namespaces?

Comment: What you have is not a namespace. I don't know what you have, but you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the [`CreateElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1k08cbx.aspx) method, the second parameter is only the namespace. Just the "`urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.02`" part.

Comment: what do I do with the 100 other xmlns:dacc insert name ?

Comment: +1. @user1354345, it is very unclear where "the 100 other xmlns" come from and why you care about them.

Comment: the prefixs are used throughout the xml.  I believe the xml namespace declaration is from a multipart namespace

Comment: What do you mean, "multi-part namespace"?